# Subscriber with lazy evaluation

Tags: go, observer-pattern

I'm looking for a solution for subscribing to attribute changes in Go. Given the below structs I'd like to implement a derived attribute which subscribes to its source attributes, and only when being read it would reevaluate itself. It would know to do so due to being notified, or by checking a "dirty flag" (channel?) if one or more of the sources had changed. 
**Edit**: I'm not looking for a "getter" function, which would not cache the fetched values, instead fethcing them every time being read). See also an added DeriveAndSubscribe-method far below, illustrating what the derived FullName would do).

I guess this resembles a fairly typical case. Se example below:

```
type Person struct {
   /FullName  string  // Derived, from the two below:
    FirstName string  // persistent
    LastName  string  // persistent
}
```

The concept must be "visible" for far subscriptions/fetches too, for example a User object deriving it's detailed user info from an underlaying Person object:

```
type User struct {
    person *Person
   /FullName string // Derived from person.FullName above
}
```

*(Ok, people's names don't change very often but the example must be simple).*

My own first thoughts on this is,

1. **Pull** - The derived attributes (FullName) is to be "lazy" (evaluated only if someone is reading it/them). Therefore it seems the most natural to "pull" any subscriptions ("dirty" flag/notification) only when evaluating the Fullname string, that is, "ask" if any change has occured.
2. **Cache** - when the value has been derived, then store it in a (hidden) field (_fullName) so that the string can be reused at next read, if its subscribed values hasn't changed.
3. **Lazy subscription** - Not only the derive operation should be "lazy" when someone reads the FullName attribute, but also the subscription itself should be laid only the first time it is evaluated (when someone reads the attribute).
4. **Good reasons for pull** instead of push seems to be that the subscribing
   attribute(s) may or may not be present when the underlaying
   attributes change. If there's no "send-list" at the source then there's
   no need to "unregister" either if/when the end subscribing attributes/objects goes away. And further; in a distributed scenario (User and Person on different machines) it's better to update things only if the data is actually explicitly asked for (that goes for the subscription as well, which can be laid only at the first read of FullName).
5. **Luxury would be** if a goroutine (optionally) could update
   (reevaluate) the FullName attribute(s) when CPU isn't very busy,
   while reevaluation would be immediately enforced if someone reads
   the FullName attribute (could both be achieved in one solution?).

In any case, here's the subscriptions that needs to be laid (ASCII model):

```
[Person]./FullName --> [Person].FirstName // Subscribe 1
                       [Person].LastName  // Subscribe 2
```

and

```
[User]./FullName --> [User].person./FullName // Subscribe 3
```

That is, alltogether three (3) subscriptons to keep the User.FullName attrib updated. (Disregard for now the [User].person-link). Can something like this be achieved using channels, and if so, um... how?

Below the above structs with the hidden fields inserted (used for caching the derived result until next time the source attributes gets "dirty"):

```
type Person struct {
   /FullName  string  // Derived
    _fullName string  // "cache"
    FirstName string  
    LastName  string  
}
```

and:

```
type User struct {
    person *Person
   /FullName  string  // Derived
    _fullName string  // "cache"
}
```

Edit: The Person-FullName-attribute could be served by a method like this one (it could be packaged into typed attribute objects (structs) later):

```
func (p *Person) _FullName_DeriveAndSubscribe(Subscriber chan) string {
    if /* check if channel(s) is "dirty" */ {
        //
        // Keep an internal channel, and get hold of the channel, or
        // Chan of Chan(?) wich can notify us if any underlaying values change:
        //
        // _subscr = Subscriber 
        //
        // Now, update the cache 
        _fullName = FirstName + " " + LastName
    }
    return _fullName   // return the cached value
}
```

Comment: I owe a beer to the first person who can explain to me what is this question about. - Undefined terms "subscribe", "source attributes". - Undefined notation "/foo", "[foo]./bar --> whatever".

Comment: @jnml I think he wants a mechanism to automagically generate / cache a struct member that can be derived from other members in a potentially expensive way.

Comment: @jnml: I've built a huge ERP systems with derivable attributes. The idea is to, yes, subscribe, to any values used by the (derived) attribute. The example is simple (and any gain's isn't obvious, but an realtime ERP system I built enabled otherwise "impossible" highspeed realtime calculations due to this kind of constructs. Made in Delphi though). Moreover, "/Fullname" is a UML notation in Rational Rose for depicting derived Attributes (as opposed to regular ones). & Ascii notation was to illustrate what elements is involved (a Neo4J notation Cypher lookalike) . Many beer, thanks. :)

Comment: I'm not sure if I got what you want to achieve, however it sounds to me as if you'd like to use reactive programming for which you might find some ideas in [this](https://github.com/trustmaster/goflow) project. But please, correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @nemo, GoFlow is a very very interesting concept! I'm afraid that it doesn't exactly address this case, but perhaps part of it (the "async" part of §5)? But I need to think b more about it. In any case, GoFlow is definitely a super interesting concept. Thank you for the tips!

Comment: @jnml: Take a look here what this is all about, and let me know if you think its worth a pint or two. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_evaluation

Comment: @ril: 'Lazy evaluation' _is_ a well defined term, no problem about it. 'Subscribe' _is not_ a well defined term generally, and especially in the context of the Go specs - nothing like that is ever mentioned there. It's not that I cannot imagine what one can mean by 'subscribe' in Go. It's about the situation where I can imagine _several_ different concepts available in Go which might deserve that name. One of the first ("subscribing") possibilities which come to my mind is receiving from a channel. Seemingly that's not what _you_ are talking about.

Comment: @jnml said: "_the context of the Go specs - nothing like that is ever mentioned there._"  I'm not mimicing Go, I'm trying to solve real problems. That is, "subscribe" is one of the better known and very well defined terms, any context. And it perfectly described what I wanted to achieve. See below, they had no problem knowing what was about, and if I ever was unclear I have really tried to clarify. Asking when something needs a clarification is not a bad idea. But don't harass people.

Answer (score 4):

http://play.golang.org/p/THNb3C-TLq

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type ChangeHandler func(interface{})

type EventedChanger interface {
    Get(name string) interface{}
    Set(name string, value interface{}) EventedChanger
    OnChange(name string, listener ChangeHandler) EventedChanger
}

type MyChanger struct {
    data      map[string]interface{}
    listeners map[string][]ChangeHandler
}

func (m *MyChanger) Get(name string) interface{} {
    val, ok := m.data[name]
    if !ok {
        return nil
    }
    return val
}

func (m *MyChanger) Set(name string, value interface{}) EventedChanger {
    m.data[name] = value
    if listeners, ok := m.listeners[name]; ok {
        for _, l := range listeners {
            l(value)
        }
    }
    return m
}

func (m *MyChanger) OnChange(name string, listener ChangeHandler) EventedChanger {
    m.listeners[name] = append(m.listeners[name], listener)
    return m
}

func NewMyChanger() *MyChanger {
    return &MyChanger{
        make(map[string]interface{}),
        make(map[string][]ChangeHandler),
    }
}

func main() {
    c := NewMyChanger()
    h := func(value interface{}) {
        c.Set("fullname", fmt.Sprint(c.Get("firstname"), c.Get("lastname")))
    }
    q := func(value interface{}) {
        fmt.Println("Full name:", value)
    }
    c.OnChange("firstname", h).OnChange("lastname", h).OnChange("fullname", q)
    c.Set("firstname", "Walter").Set("lastname", "Smith")
}
```

Output is:

```
Full name: Walter <nil>
Full name: Walter Smith

Program exited.
```

You could improve it by making it concurrent and/or execute handlers in parallel for instance.

**EDIT:**

http://play.golang.org/p/msgaBXQwt_

I have made a more *generic* version of this to comply with your requirements of being lazy and cached:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Getter func(string) interface{}

type Setter func(string, interface{})

type GetSetter interface {
    Get(string) interface{}
    Set(string, interface{}) GetSetter
    RegisterGetter(string, Getter) GetSetter
    RegisterSetter(string, Setter) GetSetter
}

type LazyGetSetter struct {
    data    map[string]interface{}
    getters map[string]Getter
    setters map[string]Setter
}

func NewLazyGetSetter() *LazyGetSetter {
    return &LazyGetSetter{
        make(map[string]interface{}),
        make(map[string]Getter),
        make(map[string]Setter),
    }
}

func (l *LazyGetSetter) Get(name string) interface{} {
    if getter, ok := l.getters[name]; ok {
        return getter(name)
    }
    if val, ok := l.data[name]; ok {
        return val
    }
    return nil
}

func (l *LazyGetSetter) Set(name string, value interface{}) *LazyGetSetter {
    if setter, ok := l.setters[name]; ok {
        setter(name, value)
    } else {
        l.data[name] = value
    }
    return l
}

func (l *LazyGetSetter) RegisterGetter(name string, getter Getter) *LazyGetSetter {
    l.getters[name] = getter
    return l
}

func (l *LazyGetSetter) RegisterSetter(name string, setter Setter) *LazyGetSetter {
    l.setters[name] = setter
    return l
}

type CachedLazyGetSetter struct {
    *LazyGetSetter
    cache map[string]interface{}
}

func NewCachedLazyGetSetter() *CachedLazyGetSetter {
    return &CachedLazyGetSetter{
        NewLazyGetSetter(),
        make(map[string]interface{}),
    }
}

func (c *CachedLazyGetSetter) Cache(name string, value interface{}) *CachedLazyGetSetter {
    c.cache[name] = value
    return c
}

func (c *CachedLazyGetSetter) FetchCache(name string) interface{} {
    if val, ok := c.cache[name]; ok {
        return val
    }
    return nil
}

func main() {
    l := NewCachedLazyGetSetter()
    l.RegisterGetter("fullname", func(name string) interface{} {
        if cached := l.FetchCache(name); cached != nil {
            return cached
        }
        f := fmt.Sprintf("%s %s", l.Get("firstname"), l.Get("lastname"))
        l.Cache(name, f)
        return f
    })
    l.Set("firstname", "Walter").Set("lastname", "Smith")
    fmt.Println(l.Get("fullname"))
}
```

As to your comment: a map lookup will outperform reflection by orders of magnitude.

Cheers!

Comment: Wow @Tom! :) This was a serious answer!  I need to chew on this one a bit. Couldn't directly read from the code if this is "pull" or "push" communication (probably mostly due to the naming). I'll be back on this when I understand the code. :) Many thanks.

Comment: I rewrote it. Sorry for the noise. BTW this would be "push" as you say.

Comment: OK, push. I can se one advantage with "push" and some disadvantages. Push would be possible to "queue" for processing asynchronesously if (while) no one reads the derived attribute. That happens fairly often so that's good. The downside with push would be to somehow having to "administer" the list of subscribers on the "sending" end. I'm a bit "afraid" of map-solutions, since they tend to be slow (...?) I'd prefer compiled struct members and I *assume* that reflection would execute faster. This is an interesting take in some cases although (even Go) systems built like this tend to be slow

Comment: I have edited my answer, please take a look at the new solution.

Comment: I changed the printing (but not the set/get-code) and the result don't seem to be the exepected. I used the code as I expected it to work, but I seem to not have understood it correctly. Se output on the playground, I renamed "word for word", and then renamed entirely to "Rob Pike". :)
http://play.golang.org/p/bJsGl76uxO

Comment: Well basically `fullname` is cached so you'll always get the thing you had when `fullname`'s getter was executed for the first time. You'll have to apply your own cache-management rules.

Answer (score 0):

Just make functions out of these derived attributes unless benchmarking shows that this is a bottleneck. In that case, you could still insert hidden (lowercase) fields to implement whatever sort of caching.

```
type Person struct {
    FirstName, LastName string
}

func (p *Person) FullName() string {
    return p.FirstName + " " + p.LastName
}
```

Comment: This is more like a regular "Getter" which is not #1. caching, and #2. not reevaluating the cached value when the underlaying attributes change. So no, this is not what I want.

Comment: As I said, design the interface this way. If and only if you find this to be the bottleneck, change the implementation into something that caches. Did you find that this was the bottleneck?

Comment: The interfaces you show are OK (and that's also what I had already done, but kept it out of the example as to not obscure the problem :). The problem is of course the derivation (which can be very deep) and the managing of the cache (invalidate as to know the need to dive deep again) The following is what I mean with "deep" (compared your return code):  return p.someLink(<-subscribe here).someotherLink(<-subscribe also here).yetAnotherLink.(<-subscribe here also).FirstName + " " + p.someLink(<-subscribe here).someotherLink(<-subscribe here too).LastName(<-subscribe). -> Bad caching==COSTLY!